# Remove same-named files from subfolder

Tags: file-management, cvs

Given the following layout, how can I delete files in the Attic folders which have a corresponding file in the parent folder? (The files will have the same name, not necessarily the same contents)

```
/folder1
    /Attic
        fileA.txt,v  (problem file)
    fileA.txt,v
    fileB.txt,v
    FileC.txt,v
/folder2
    /Attic
        fileD.txt,v  (another problem file)
        fileX.txt,v  (NOT a problem file)
    fileD.txt,v
    fileE.txt,v
    FileF.txt,v
```

Background: I'm trying to clean up a CVS repository for migration to git. CVS creates an 'Attic' folder for deleted files.  Over the last 10 years some Bad Things have happened, which means some files with the same name exist in both the alive and dead folders.  I am fully aware of the risks and implications. I have backed up my data and I'm working on a copy.

Comment: I'd have expected cvs-fast-export to deal with such situations properly (afaik, they're not infrequent) – are you sure it won't actually migrate the repository correctly?

Comment: I'll have to investigate. I'm using cvs2git, and not entirely at home in a unix terminal. There doesn't appear to be an option to discard the conflicting Attic files.

Comment: Try cvs-fast-export then. See http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=5190 and http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=4745 as well.

Comment: Didn't get a chance to look at the above two links - Firewall rules at work don't like certain types of message boards/forums. Your script did the trick though, and I now have a reference to work from if face with a similar (file-management) problem in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```
shopt -s globstar;
for file in ./**/Attic/*; do
    if [[ -e ${file%/*/*}/${file##*/} ]]; then
        rm -vf "$file";
    fi;
done;
```

With *globstar* enabled, `**` matches files recursively (regardless of depth). `${var#text}` and `${var%text}` allow removing the prefix or suffix of a variable, so `${file%/*/*}` results in the directory name (minus "/Attic/…"), while `${file##*/}` is the base filename.

You should also consider tools like `cvs-fast-export` and `reposurgeon`; I'd expect them to correctly deal with such situations from the beginning. If not, then at least make sure you have the most recent version of `cvs2git`...

Comment: This works a treat, thank you! As a bonus, it is not thrown by filenames with spaces or the ,v. Much appreciated!